# Batch sendemail automatically without clicking send

Tags: batch-file, outlook, batch-processing

I use Microsoft Outlook for emailing.

My batch script does some checking and I want it to send out email automatically without me doing any clicking manually.

I have this code in my batch file.

```
START mailto:me@myemail.com?Subject=TEST^&body=TEST_MSG.
```

all code creates new email in outlook with subject, email and body filled but it doesn't actually send it without me clicking send.

Can someone help pls?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to send an e-mail message from a batch file (shell script) is to use a command-line mail application such as [blat](http://www.blat.net/). However you will need to know the name (or address) of the SMTP server to use as well as permission to send. For that information, contact your network administrator.

Comment: I don't have access to that, and I can't install third party apps on my machine, do I stand any other chance with batch and outlook?

Comment: Blat does not require any kind of installation; it is a standalone executable (single file, blat.exe). It is possible to use Outlook automation to send an e-mail message but this would require a WSH script rather than a batch file (shell script). Blat is much simpler and more straightforward.

Comment: I can't use blat I guess. windows is just stupid at some points.

Comment: Your comment is unfortunately unhelpful to work toward to an answer to your question. You need to be more specific about what you mean.

Comment: I tried installing blat it didn't allowing me to install via command `balt intall server email`

Comment: As I already mentioned, you don't need to install anything. Just run the blat.exe program with the appropriate command-line arguments. It would be helpful for you to read the [documentation](http://www.blat.net/examples/install&profile.html) for the program before using it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I think he's saying he does not have an external SMTP server he can use with Blat.